# Adding geojson features to OpenMapTiles displayed with MapboxGLJS is not working

Tags: openstreetmap, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js, osm2vectortiles

The [*OpenMapTiles* example for display using Mapbox GL JS](https://openmaptiles.org/docs/website/mapbox-gl-js/) works nicely to display the map.  However, when trying to add lines and features to the map using Mapbox GL JS functions like this:

```
map.on('load', function () { map.addLayer({ .... }) })
```

the desired added lines and features do not display on the map.  The full example HTML is shown below.

Questions:

- Is there something about the *openmaptiles* style osm-bright that makes it incompatible which the specified data as added below?
- Could it be made to work by changing something in the code below?
- Could it be made to work by changing something in the osm-bright style file?

The added code for geojson features are mapbox examples:

- https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-markers/
- https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-line/

The features should appear in and around San Francisco.

Here is the whole HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>OpenMapTiles OSM Bright style</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'https://openmaptiles.github.io/osm-bright-gl-style/style-cdn.json',
            center: [8.5456, 47.3739],
            zoom: 11
        });


      map.on('load', function () {

      map.addLayer({
      "id": "points",
      "type": "symbol",
      "source": {
      "type": "geojson",
      "data": {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-122.414, 37.776]
      },
      "properties": {
      "title": "Mapbox SF",
      "icon": "harbor"
      }
      }]
      }
      },
      "layout": {
      "icon-image": "{icon}-15",
      "text-field": "{title}",
      "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
      "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
      "text-anchor": "top"
      }
      });


      map.addLayer({
      "id": "route",
      "type": "line",
      "source": {
      "type": "geojson",
      "data": {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
      [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
      [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
      [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
      [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
      [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971],
      [-122.48404026031496, 37.83049717427869],
      [-122.48348236083984, 37.829920943955045],
      [-122.48356819152832, 37.82954808664175],
      [-122.48507022857666, 37.82944639795659],
      [-122.48610019683838, 37.82880236636284],
      [-122.48695850372314, 37.82931081282506],
      [-122.48700141906738, 37.83080223556934],
      [-122.48751640319824, 37.83168351665737],
      [-122.48803138732912, 37.832158048267786],
      [-122.48888969421387, 37.83297152392784],
      [-122.48987674713133, 37.83263257682617],
      [-122.49043464660643, 37.832937629287755],
      [-122.49125003814696, 37.832429207817725],
      [-122.49163627624512, 37.832564787218985],
      [-122.49223709106445, 37.83337825839438],
      [-122.49378204345702, 37.83368330777276]
      ]
      }
      }
      },
      "layout": {
      "line-join": "round",
      "line-cap": "round"
      },
      "paint": {
      "line-color": "#888",
      "line-width": 8
      }
      });
      });


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mapbox-gl-js` version number in the OpenMapTiles was too old.  The OpenMapTiles example is using version `0.29.0`.  The current version is `0.45.0`.

Changing

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

to

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

allowed the added geojson data to become visible.